# update snapshot.jar to timestamp.jar

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, leiningen

Am pushing the jar file to jfrog artifactory using lein deploy it goes to the artifactory as
**stamper-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** but it should be going as ***context-0.1.0-20210728.151214-1.jar***
maven version 3.0.5
lein version 2.9.3

Comment: 1) You're not "_pushing_" to a remote Maven repo. You _deploy_ to it. Pushing is for Git SCM repos. 2) Maven's convention and default for artifact names is [`<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM). Why do you want to confuse people by changing the _artifactId_ in the JAR's name? 3) Usually artifacts in the local Maven repo have a qualifier `-SNAPSHOT`. Once deployed to a remote repo managed by a repo manager, like Artifactory, the `-SNAPSHOT` qualifier is replaced with a timestamp you mention secondly by the repo mgr.

Comment: See also [_How does Maven resolve SNAPSHOT dependencies when there are SNAPSHOTS with different timestamps in the local and the remote repository?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32416454/1744774).

Comment: Really using Maven 3.0.5? Please upgrade as soon as possible..  https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue to resolve this need to change our Maven Snapshot Version Behavior = unique